# Order Custom WordPress Posts by Custom Field using Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to order a set of custom post by time using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF). Using [this help page](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/) and the [WP_Query page from the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), I've gotten to the code below, but it only sorts by the post title, I want it to sort by the custom field `start_time` I've created.

Here are some of the possible key/values a user can pick:

a : 6:00am

b : 6:15am

c : 6:30am

d : 6:45am

And here is a simplified version of the template code:

```
<?php $args = array( 
'post_type' => 'events', 
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby'           => 'meta_value_char',
'meta_key'          => 'start_time',
'order'             => 'ASC'
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <ul> 
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <li>
        <?php the_title(); ?>: <?php the_field( "start_time" ); ?>
    </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Which outputs this:

- A Event: 7:45am
- B Event: 4:15pm
- C Event: 7:45am
- D Event: 2:30pm
- E Event: 10:15am

So it's ordering the posts by the event title, not the time field. how can I make it order by the time field I created? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have three options for you. I have not tested them.

Orderby can accept more than one argument.

```
'orderby'  => 'meta_value meta_value_char'
```

Is the time is stored as a num? Then try these. One at a time, not together.

```
'orderby'  => 'meta_value meta_value_num'

'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num'
```

I hope that helps.

Best.

Comment: That's it! `meta_value meta_value_char` was the answer. Thank you thank you!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help. Mind up voting the answer?

Comment: I tried to vote it up, but I don't have enough reputation points, if I accrue them at a later date somehow, I will though. :)